# suggestions for migrating a windows 7 install to a new 4K sector disk

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, migration

I'm looking to upgrade the disk on a windows 7 box to a new larger drive.

In the past for such migrations I'd just hook both drives up and use a linux boot disk and use dd to copy from one disk to the next... boot up the new drive & expand the partition.

The drive I just purchased however is a western digital using 4k sectors... not sure if there'd be any complications using my old method moving from a 512b sector drive.

Current plan is to try the migration by doing a win7 system image backup to an external drive... then restore the image to the new drive via system restore boot disk.  Any suggestions or recommendations on how to best complete this migration would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your method (win7 system image backup) should work just fine.

Comment: Seems like it is only pre Vista OSs that have issue with 4K sectors, as snorfys said, a W7 image should restore just fine using the W7 recovery Environment. Not sure if linux would have issues or not.

Comment: I'd never migrate an install - always install fresh! It only takes a few hours and always has performance benefits

Comment: @roryok You’ve obviously never had any programs installed.

Comment: @kinokijuf ninite reinstalls 90% of them with no effort, there are a couple left after that but I have the install files on an external HD. I'm including all that in the "few hours" it takes.